# Type-checking correct key-value usage in a returned object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a (generated) type definition for possible response bodies:

```js
type ResponseMap = {
  '200': { 'ok': true },
  '404': { 'error': true, type: 'NotFound' },
  '500': null,
}
```

I want to write a function which would return objects in the shape of `{ code, body }` checked against the typing above.

The best I was able to accomplish is the following:

```js
type Codes<Bodies> = keyof Bodies

type ResponseCodeBodyPair<Bodies extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  code: Codes<Bodies>,
  body: Bodies[Codes<Bodies>]
}

function endpoint(): ResponseCodeBodyPair<ResponseMap> {
  if (Math.random()) {
    return { code: '200', body: { 'ok': true } }
  }
  if (Math.random()) {
    return { code: '404', body: { 'error': true, type: 'NotFound' } }
  }
  if (Math.random()) {
    return { code: '500', body: null }
  }

  // This should fail since { ok: true } is not a valid body for 404.
  return { code: '404', body: { 'ok': true } }
}
```

This check that there are no unknown status codes returned by the function and that all returned bodies correspond with one of the possible body shapes.

What it does not check is the correctness of code-to-body pairing as demonstrated by the last return.

How can I limit the type to the precise body shape for a status code here?

I would need something like

```js
type ResponseCodeBodyPair<Bodies extends Record<string, unknown>> =
  Code extends keyof Bodies ?  { code: Code, body: Bodies[Code] } : never
```

…but that does not work of course.

I was struggling with the same many times and always gave up. Is it actually not possible or am I missing something?

---

P.S. I know it would be OK if the type were `{ code: '200', body: … } | { code: '404', … } | …` but I do not have that available. That is why I need to somehow transform the map/record to this union type.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the right way to do this.

I can map the `{ [Code]: Response }` object onto a `{ [Code]: { code: Code, body: Response } }` object and take the values of this object via `T[keyof T]` which results in the exact type I need.

```js
type ResponseCodeBodyPairMap<M> = {
  [Code in keyof M]: { code: Code, body: M[Code] }
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type ResponseCodeBodyPair<M> = Values<ResponseCodeBodyPairMap<M>>
```

Comment: That was creative!